# Moving cursor with trackpad is not working. How to fix it?

Tags: mouse, trackpad

Today morning after starting my computer, I noticed very weird behavior with my trackpad cursor is on the top corner and I can't move it at all however click is working, bottom click is working. Here are some things I have already tried:

- Reset the settings related to the trackpad.
- Reset SMC.
- Reset NVRAM/PRAM.
- In the end, I reinstalled the OS as well.
- Ran hardware diagnostic(with long press on D while starting up) and it showed no problems at all.

One issue I found after reinstalling the MacOS was that in the ~/Library/Preferences any plist file related to Trackpad was missing. I was expecting `com.apple.AppleMultitouchTrackpad.plist`, which is not there.

This computer is 2017 version of Macbook Air.

Any help on this would be very much appreciated. Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: did you find any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

After all the things you already did, I would think a hardware defect is most likely. Plist files won't exist until you change some settings.

Comment: I ran through the hardware diagnostic as well. It says everything is fine.

Comment: @rahul_pratap Hardware diagnostics can not detect each and every problem. If the data it gets from the trackpad's chip looks normal, it will declare it working. If you already disconnected all external hardware, reset the SMC and NVRAM, then re-installed the OS to a clean HDD/SSD, and the problem still persists, I don't see any possibillity for it being a software problem anymore.

Comment: It may be, I'll consult apple support.